# Spring Webflow (and Freemarker) - restrict page to one user

Tags: spring, freemarker, spring-webflow

I am working on an application with Spring Webflow, Freemarker, Hibernate (JPA) and Oracle.

In the application I've got an **Admin page** which should be **editable to only one user**.
Once a user is editing that page, other user accessing should be presented this page as a **view only** page and they should get a warning when they open the page that '*X is editing this page, thus your access is read only*'.

Is this possible to do easily in Webflow or Freemarker?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

I am using JPA (Hibernate) as well.

**UPDATE 2**

And the application will be deployed in a clustered JBoss.

Comment: And what if the admin editing this page doesn't submit the edit? All the others wait until his session times out some day? Why don't you use optimistic locking instead?

Comment: That's the plan actually. And can you please explain how to do optimistic locking?

Answer (score 4):

I would use optimistic locking instead. The following strategy is the one used by JPA.

You add a `version` field to the table holding the data to edit. Each time you load the data to edit, you also load the `version` field. Each time the data is modified, you increment this version field by 1. But to be able to save the data, you must have an in-memory version that is equal to the one stored in database:

```
update data set ..., version = version + 1 where ... and version = :inMemoryVersion
```

If the above query doesn't update anything, it means the data has been updated by someone else. In this case, you throw an exception and tell the admin to refresh the page and redo his edit.

If you really want pessimistic locking, then you need to maintain some in-memory (in the app is not clustered) or in-database lock, try to lock the lock, and display the page in read-only if it's already locked. Once the update is done, you must release the lock. The problem is if the update is never done. In this case, you need to use an `HttpSessionListener`, and release the lock when `sessionDestroyed()` is called, if the lock is held by the session being destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, optimistic locking looks good. In my original post I forgot to mention that I am using Hibernate as well (updated now). Does hibernate provide 'optimistic locking' out-of-the-box?

Comment: I've read few sites about 'optimistic locking' and it should work. But how will I show a message e.g. 'X is editing this page, thus your access is read only' in a popup to other users. I need to know the name of the person who has locked the functionality. And my requirement is not about locking the row, it is more about locking a functionality.

Comment: If you use optimistic locking, there's no point in doing that. The point of optimistic locking is to let everyone work as if others didn't exist, and be optimistic that there won't be any conflict. If there is one, you detect it. Yes, Hibernate supports it out of the box. If you need to make the page read-only, then use pessimistic as I explained, and associate the name of the locker with the lock.